# UIButton background image offset

Tags: ios, uibutton, offset

Is there a way to add some sort of offset to `UIButton`'s background image?

I've got some custom background images for `UIButton`. These images do have a 5 pixel drop shadow area around the effective button area. When I use these images I have to move the title label around, adjust the frame and do some calculations to place the buttons correctly.

Ideally, I would like to set something like an **offset** (x = -5px, y = -5px) on that image (or the `UIButton`) so that when I assign the image as a background to the UIButton it is moved by that offset horizontally and vertically.

In html I would set a fixed size on the button div and then **offset** the background image by specifying background-position.

Is there something similar for iOS?

Comment: You can use button title/content insets.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Setting `setTitleEdgeInsets:` or `setImageEdgeInsets:` do not seem to have any effect on the **background** image of an `UIButton` but only on the **image** (and the title).

I ended up with overriding `-(CGRect)backgroundRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds` where I inflate the bounds rectangle by the amount needed (5 in my case).

Comment: This is the best answer. Make a subclass of UIButton and override `-(CGRect)backgroundRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds`.

Answer (score 13):

This is an old question, but I think the answer could be better. One way to do this is to get ahold of your button and then grab its image. So, if you've setup your buttons in IB it might look like this in objc:

`UIImage *i = [self.button backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal];`

If you did it in code, then you already have these things!

And then you want to setup your alignment rect to adjust for the difference.

`i = [i imageWithAlignmentRectInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -5, -5)];`

(top, left, bottom, right).

Now set the button image back.

```
[self.button setBackgroundImage:i forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Auto layout uses alignment rects to line things up. You might have to change some constants on your alignments to fine tune.

Answer (score 2):

Just updating SmileBot answer:

Create a button (in my case an UIBarButtonItem) programatically and set its background image with offset (+2 px in top edge):

### Swift 3

```
let image = UIImage(named: "yourimagename")!.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 0, 0, 0))
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
button.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIControlState())
```

Answer (score 1):

In attribute inspector for UIbuton you can set the title/image inset value.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can play with both `setTitleEdgeInsets:` and `setImageEdgeInsets:` to get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for offset

```
[buttonName setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 12.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
```